# Show this function has infinitely many critical points and classify;

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Show that $$f(x,y)=x^2-x+\cos(xy)$$has inifinitely many critical points and classify;

**Partial Derivative w.r.t. $x$** $$f_{x}=2x-1-y\sin(xy)=0$$
**Partial Derivative w.r.t. $y$** $$f_{y}=-x\sin(xy)=0$$
Now trying to simultaneously solve; you get that $$\sin(xy)=\dfrac{1-2x}{x-y}$$ is that enough to show infinite solutions?
And how would I classify these?, use the hessian method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\partial_2 f=0
$$
implies either $x=0$ or $\sin (xy)=0$. If $\sin (xy)=0$, then $\partial_1 f=0$ becomes $x=1/2$, and hence $\sin (y/2)=0$. This equation has infinitely many solutions.

If $x=0$, then $y \sin (0)=-1$, which is impossible. Now you should try to compute the hessian matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any restrictions on x and y then when you equate $f_y$ = 0 u get $sinxy = 0$  which is true for infinitely values

Comment: This is not enough: you must solve a system, not a single equation!